# How to post a list of complicated object to struts2

Tags: jquery, ajax, list, object, struts2

I want to send a list of User object into action, while user has field name and address here.

Some code like this: The webpage is dynamic manipulated by jquery. there is sample code of webpage.

```
<form id="create">
  <tr id="1"> <td> <input type='text' name='name'/></td><td><input type='text' name='address'/></td></tr>
  <tr id="3"> <td> <input type='text' name='name'/></td><td><input type='text' name='address'/></td></tr>
</form>
<input type='submit' onclick="submit()"/>


<script>
  function submit() {
    var results = [];
    $("#create tr").each(function(index, tr) {
      var user = {
        name: tr.find('input[name="name"]').val(),
        address: tr.find('input[name="address"]').val()
      }
      results.push(user);
    });

    var param = {users:results};
    $.ajax({
      url: "save.action",
      data: param,
      type: 'post',
      success: function() {
        alert('success');  
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('error');  
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Action code like this:

```
@ParentPackage('json-default')
public class UserAction extends ActionSupport {
  private List<User> users;
  public List<User> getUsers(){
     return users;
  }
  public void setUsers(List<User> users){
     this.users = users;
  }

@Action(name="save", results={@Result{name="success",location="/webpage/addUser.jsp"}})
public String execute(){
 for(User user: Users){
    System.out.println(user.getName()+" address: "+ user.getAddress());
 }
 return SUCCESS; 
}
}
```

My question is **why the action can't receive the data?**
I capture the data from firebug and the data has been posted.
So any hint or something wrong?
I was confused here two days, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery 1.4 you should consider that there is a change about param serialization. JQuery provides a new flag in $.ajax to override the default behavior (and go back to use the old way of param serialization): the "traditional" option in $.ajax So you should try that to send data over Ajax at JQuery:

```
....
$.ajax({
    url:"save.action",
    data:param,
    type:'post',
    traditional: true,
....
```

Comment: @lykm You may try $.ajaxSettings.traditional = true; or jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true; (depends on your JQuery version) before the line of $.ajax({...); (I mean after the line of var param = {users:results}; at your code), it should be written before you send the data via Ajax.

Comment: thanks, actually I am not familiar with jquery. The version is 1.4.4. I will try it.

Comment: I don't know whether jquery can serialize the case. I mean when serialize a list of object. There is no such example can found.

Comment: Thanks very much. I found the real problem. When set traditional=true, struts will receive a javascript object, which can't convert into User. And when traditional=false, jquery serialize the user:{name:'john'} into user[name]='john', which struts can't recognize. The solution is modify the param method of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

If Firebug is indicating that the data is being successfully posted, then I would recommend that you do some debugging on the Java side to confirm that.

Try placing a break point and viewing the actual `HttpServletRequest` parameters that are coming in to make sure that they are being set properly. If they are, then make sure that your `setUsers(List<User> user)` method is being called. This should point out exactly where the failure is occurring.

Comment: Thanks, I find in the request. The users are three object ,[object Object]. So, anywhere wrong? does that mean serialize fails?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the rest of your jsp, action and exactly what you are posting back to your action. Without seeing the rest I would guess that you are not handling in-situ list updating correctly. If you were using "traditional" HTML I would expect to see a reference to the users list index in both the HTML and the returned data so that Struts knows which list elements to update/create.

Regards

Comment: As you can see from the page, there are almost whole info in my program. There are some wrong in the ajax serialize. But I still confused.